# Back and forth oscillation of a screw

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

When you tend to give a screw a small push when it is resting on a relatively smooth surface, it tends to oscillate/move **back and forth** in a circular path before stopping. There is no apparent torque in the opposite direction of push, which makes this motion very non-intuitive. You can try it yourself as well by taking a screw and pushing it slightly(not too hard). If someone can please explain the physics behind this motion, it would be really helpful...

Answer (score 2):

The torque actually comes from the threading on the screws. Because the threads on the screw aren't rotationally symmetric there is a certain preferred angle for the screw to rest at as the mass of the screw is then not distributed evenly. If you move it from this angle by pushing it slightly the screw will rotate and the threads with more mass will have a gravitational force on them applying a torque to the screw. Although I will admit that thinking about the torques here is rather weird. This problem is probably easier to think about in terms of potentials. The gravitational potential is given by:
$$U=mgh$$
The configuration that the screw rests at is such that the center of mass of the screw is as low as possible because physical systems seek to minimize potential locally. What this means is that if you push the screw and raise its center of mass it will then want to come back to a configuration where its center of mass is at the lowest possible point so it will rotate back to achieve this. The reason for the oscillation is that it will overshoot coming back so it will raise the mass again and get pushed the other direction, much like a ball rolling back and forth in a valley. If you want to see this for yourself you could take the screw and twist it 180 degrees and then put it on the table, without even needing to push it it will start moving as you put it at a high potential energy and it will oscillate around the low potential until friction stops it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, never really considered the uneven distribution of the threads and how they might impact the motion as  well!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question.

There can be a few possible but related reasons.

– There is most likely a small depression in the table, or a tilt to it. Just like a marble rolling in a bowl, it will accelerate by gravity until it reaches its lowest point, and its kinetic energy will carry it past this lowest point until gravity arrests its motion and begins the cycle again. This would continue indefinitely, but friction robs some energy each time until the oscillations die down.

– Even on a perfectly flat table, the screw may not be perfectly symmetrical.  It may have a "heavy" side that wants to be the lowest point. This can cause the same oscillation behavior as above.

– Finally, even on a perfectly flat table with a perfectly symmetrical screw, when the screw reaches the very end of its roll due to friction, a slight elasticity in the microscopic irregularities of the table surface may cause a "rebound" effect – like when you bring your car to a complete stop, you feel it rebound a fraction of an inch due to the elasticity in the tires and the frame. My intuition tells me this last effect is probably too small to set the screw rolling back the way it came, and you would likely observe nearly a dead stop.

In general, any time you have a restoring force that acts to bring a system back into a central, lowest energy position (pendulum, marble in a bowl, two H atoms covalently bonded in $\rm H_2$, diving board, any spring) you will see this oscillating behavior.